# Standard terminology for n/gcd(n,m).

Tags: terminology

Let $n,m$ be positive integers. Is there a standard terminology and notation for the quotient of $n$ divided by the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $m$, i.e., for the integer $\frac{n}{\gcd(n,m)} = \frac{\mathrm{lcm}(n,m)}{m}$?

Comment: I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Ivaguely remember this being named $n'$, $\widehat{n} $, or something like that.